# Ember.js Receiving "Uncaught TypeError" for action in controller

Tags: html, ember.js, controller, action, typeerror

I am receiving this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'
```

when I try to use a 'save' action that I have defined in my controller.

Here is my HTML code

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each}}
      <tr class="people-list">
        <td>        
          <div class="category-text">
            {{input type="text" class="quick-add-element" action="save"  valueBinding=Name}}
            {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
              {{Name}}
            {{/linkTo}}
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

Here is my category controller

```
actions: {
   save: function(){
     var category = this.get('model');
     // this will tell Ember-Data to save/persist the new record
     category.save();
     // then transition to the current user
     this.transitionToRoute('category', category);
        }
}
```

and my categories controller

```
actions: {
   save: function(){
     var category = this.get('model');
     // this will tell Ember-Data to save/persist the new record
     category.save();
     // then transition to the current user
     this.transitionToRoute('category', category);
        }
}
```

My Category Route

```
VpcYeoman.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
  serialize: function(model){
    return {category_id: model.get('id')};
  }, 
});
```

Comment: What template is the HTML code from?

Comment: It's hard to debug this from just code snippets. It would be much easier if you could put together a jsBin for us.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to properly answer this question, but let's see. I'm assuming in you have a well defined Category model. Now, your router should have these two routes with their corresponding model hooks implemented. Without these, the controller will not have the proper models.

Also, the save function in the categories controller will not work. The model for the categories controller is an array of models which is why you can't call save on it. Either the saving has to happen within the categoryController (which has a single model and calling save it on works), or the categoriesController needs to have the id of the model it needs to save (you'll have to search the array model for the id and then call save on the record)

This is how your routes are supposed to look like:

```
VpcYeoman.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('categories', function() {
    this.route('category');
  });
});

VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find("category")
  }, 
 });

VpcYeoman.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
  model: function(category){
    return this.store.find("category", category.category_id)
  }, 
 });
```

Take a look at how they do it here:

https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs/js